# Do I need to shade my veggie garden during a heat wave?

Tags: vegetables, plant-health, hot-weather

We are expected to have 100+ degrees Fahrenheit for the next 3 days. My plants are already looking pretty wilted. They get 12 hours of sunlight, often dry and windy as well. I'm really worried I will lose some of the weaker plants during this heat, but I don't want to shade them if I will hurt them from growing.

I have two tomato plants (beefeater, and cherry tomatos), a yellow bell pepper and red bell pepper, an eggplant and a jalapeno pepper. And two blueberry bushes.

Comment: What part of the world are you in? When did you plant your garden? What stage (i guess the best word) are your plants in?Are they starting to flower? Is fruit already growing on them? Is fruit ripening? I know tomatoes do well with shade cloth in high heat. Dry and windy can harm peppers. Above 95 degrees for a few days and blossoms can drop from tomatoes. Above 90 for peppers.

Comment: Some sort of windbreak or fence would also appear to be advisable, if you have hot, dry winds.

Comment: one beefeater tomato has not produced fruit yet, flowers appear dry and sometimes fall off. Cherry tomato plant is doing well, lots of tomatos growing, but leaves are curling in and some appear dry. yellow pepper has one good sized fruit, but other flowers fell off. all other plants (red pepper, jalapeno and eggplant) flowers have fallen off, no fruit to bear.

Comment: I'm in northern California - central valley between Sacramento and Livermoore. Sunny all the time 90 degrees F on average and often windy. Much hotter temps than I've ever grown in before (I had a garden in San Jose, which was probably 10 degrees cooler on average about 70 to 80 degrees F).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For tomatoes: yes, they don't like very high temperature. On professional greenhouses, it is customary to shadows them on summer.

I think aubergine could have similar problem, and heat could block the growth of the fruits, so when they have better temperature they could take strange forms, or not growth again.

I don't think peppers would have problems (but also no problem if you shadow them).

Answer (score 4):

Providing some shade during the hottest part of the day (usually roughly between 11-3 pm) if the sun is shining would be beneficial in such high temperatures, but sometimes, it's hot without sunshine, in which case, there's not much point in providing shade. If its dry and particularly windy as well, and the plants are already wilting, you certainly need to increase your watering,

Answer (score 1):

I am in the San Francisco/Bay Area and we occasionally get 100 degree days as well.  I don't have any shelter in my raised beds to protect from the sun and my peppers and tomatoes do just fine.  The only thing I have to do is ensure I am watering them manually (in addition to the automatic drip) so that they don't start wilting.  I do have my house fence which provides some wind protection but not a whole lot.  As suggested, it would also depend on where you are located.